# HTML/Javascript - Using <select> value to act as a condition

Tags: javascript, html, list, select, dropdown

I'm trying to make it so that depending on what value you select from the drop down list, the

and  attributes below it will display a different thing. Why wont it work?

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function listSelect() 
    {
        var theList = document.getElementbyId(poi);
        var theValue = theList.options[theList.selectedIndex].value;
        if (theValue.includes('country'))   
        {
            document.getElementbyId('poiImage').src='images/country.jpg';
            document.getElementbyId('poiText').innerHTML='this is country';
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id=poi onchange="listSelect()">
    <option value="country">Countryside</option>
    <option value="cathedral">Cathedral</option>
    <option value="park">Park</option>
</select>
<br/>
<img id=poiImage height=150px width=180px>
<p id=poiText></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementbyId(poi);`  Looks like you're missing quotes.  Typo?  It's also `getElementById`, case sensative

Comment: You're right, I thought it would be something like that. Thank you Taplar!